# GAE - How to Multi Delete Blobs

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

With NDB you can delete multiple records at once using ndb.delete_multi(list of keys).  I have not been able to find similar functionality with the BlobStore thus each key needs to be iterated through and deleted.  Is there a more efficient way similar to delete_multi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[google.appengine.ext.blobstore.delete](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/functions) can take a list of blob-keys.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. I am not sure why the Blobstore documentation doesn't also call this out.  It just references a single delete.  Great find!

Answer (score 0):

What logic will you use to determine which to delete?  Can you query for it?

```
old_stuff = MyStuff.query(MyStuff.date_created < old_date).fetch(keys_only=True)
ndb.delete_multi(old_stuff)
```

Comment: In my case I store the Blob key in an NDB table with related data.  I can put those keys in a list and delete it with the function that Greg mentioned above.